# Whatsapp Cloud API

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

Can Whatsapp Cloud API be used for business as a reseller?
like what is the difference between the new Whatsapp Cloud API and the API we get from Resellers?

Also, is there an API to automate the signup process?

Answer (score 4):

Those Resellers you mention are often Business Solution Providers (BSPs), or BSP partners.

So that implies, in order to be WhatsApp Cloud API reseller, you will need to be either a BSP or BSP partner.

> The Cloud API architecture significantly simplifies the BSP’s operational and infrastructure requirements to integrate with WhatsApp Business Platform.

See "What is the architecture of the Cloud API?", in [Cloud API FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/faqs)

As a BSP or its partner, a reselling program is available to you both for **On-premises/Managed WhatsApp Business API** and **Cloud API**. **However**, you need to take into account Cloud API is relatively new and all BSPs are currently adapting/expanding their current solutions to new service offered by Meta.

In other words, Cloud API is not yet available everywhere and current services offered by BSPs are more versatile and feature rich than Cloud API until this will eventually change.

The largest WhatsApp BSP is [360dialog](https://www.360dialog.com/), offering WhatsApp Business API integration Platform as a Service, and on-premises plans.

Since you asked about differences between Cloud API and BSPs, let me give a short comparison between Cloud API and 360dialog **key differences**, as an example:

| Differences | 360dialog | Meta Cloud API |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Message Throughput (Per Second)** | Flexible scalability setups for small to large businesses. Send up to 70 text messages per second for single-connect. **Send up to 250 text messages per second** for multi-connect. | Up to 80 messages per second of combined sending and receiving (inclusive of text and media messages). In the event of high system loads, a business may experience reduced message throughput. **Starting in July 2022, support up to 250 messages per second of combined sending and receiving** (inclusive of text and media messages), by request |
| **SLA - Uptime** | Standard and Premium support with different SLAs: >99%, >98% | Goals of 99.9% at GraphAPI. |
| **SLA - Disaster Recovery** | Average response time of 4h. Escalation Path to Meta team after 360dialog investigation. | No SLA |

Sources:

- [Full comparison table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/overview#on-premises-api-vs--cloud-api-comparison) of differences between On-premises and Cloud API solutions.
- [360dialog Pricing](https://www.360dialog.com/whatsapp-business-api#pricing)

So, as you might've noticed, with BSP will work more closely with you as a solution provider and will offer you more flexibility depending on the business scale.

WhatsApp Business API requires some developer effort, but there are also different WhatsApp API based solutions that make this whole process a lot easier.

One of them is [get.chat WhatsApp Business Team Inbox & WhatsApp Integration API](https://get.chat/) which will help you to integrate with WhatsApp much faster. Plus, it will enable access to non-technical people in your team/company, too!

I am a co-founder and CTO so I am open to answer any questions if you want to know more about our solution. Here is also a link to [the docs](https://docs.get.chat/) if you're interested in learning more by yourself.

Further reading:

- [An easy guide about WhatsApp Business API by get.chat](https://get.chat/how-to-use-whatsapp-business-api/)
- [Cloud API FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/faqs) - offered by Meta directly
- [On-premises WhatsApp Business API FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/faq/) - hosted by BSPs and resellers

Answer (score 0):

now there are two types of Whatsapp Business API. The ones from the diferent Busniness Solution Providers (BSP) and the one from Meta (Whatsapp CloudAPI).
I think that untill now, each BSP has develped it´s own APIS starting off the one provided by Meta. So each BSP offeres his own APIs (endpoints, libraries..).
Meta has now published the API offered to the BSP and now every business has direct access to it. No more BSP are needed, unless you want and easy to use solution.
The main difference I see between BSP and Meta API is that BSP are easier to use. MetaAPI is a huge complex system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't need to look at BSP, all you can do is set up, create a business account and developer effort to make things work according to your business desire, and create message templates.

please have a below link for further eloboration.

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/338665938087159